# Linux: load module based on another module

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

Is it possible to dynamically load (via `MOD_ALIAS()` maybe?) a module that requires another module to first be loaded?

Background: I have a USB->I2C bridge on my system, and attached to the i2c end is a touchscreen. The kernel module that brings up the i2c automatically loads/unloads whenever the USB cable is connected/disconnected. I'm looking for a way to also load/unload the touchscreen driver on the same events.

Answer (score 1):

You're talking about module dependencies, generated by depmod -A. The actual dependency information is stored in /lib/modules/version/modules.dep.

If /lib/modules/2.6.29/kernel/a.ko depends on b.ko (in the same directory) you could add the line:

```
/lib/modules/2.6.29/kernel/a.ko: /lib/modules/2.6.29/kernel/b.ko
```

To create the dependency.

Comment: I don't know that this helps me. foo.ko is loaded/unloaded dynamically based on usb plug events, and is unaware of the other module, bar.ko. bar.ko needs to be loaded *after* foo.ko is loaded. If I created a dependency from foo.ko to bar.ko, bar.ko will fail in its init function because it needs foo.ko to be loaded first

Comment: Ah I see. I believe you're into udev rulesets then. There's a way of doing them for USB so that when you hotplug in a USB device, you can do pretty much anything, including running a script. Unfortunately I don't know much about udevadm, sorry...

Answer (score 1):

> What you want is **[modprobe.d](http://linux.die.net/man/5/modprobe.d)**

Add a `<module>.conf` file where `<module>` is the name of your kernel module that is dynamically loaded.

Define the `install` and `remove` options within the above conf file to run the relevant commands instead of the `modprobe` (in the required order).

If you want to automatically load the module **bob** after loading the module **alice**,

```
# /etc/modprobe.d/alice.conf
install alice /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install alice;  /sbin/modprobe bob;
```

The `--ignore-install`, stops the `modprobe` from running the same install command again.

Similarly define the `remove` section within the same conf file.
For more details, checkout the **[man page of modprobe.d](http://linux.die.net/man/5/modprobe.d)**.

Comment: How do we do this with built-in drivers which are loaded at the beginnning

Comment: Is the double quote (") at the end a mistake?